# How do you write a regex in python that finds all word which contain only letters, numbers and underscore?

Tags: python, regex

This is the best I was able to come up with:

```
b = re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]\b', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_')
```

But that doesn't work.  Also, not that I'm only interested in regexes at the moment.  I can solve the problem the long way.

The expected result is a list containing [ahz2gb_, heyght78_]

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? What is your expected and actual result?

Comment: at least you try adding a `+` after your `[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple to understand will be regex ..

- `^[0-9a-zA-Z_]+$` : strictly numbers, alphabets and underscore
- `^[0-9a-zA-Z_ ]+$` : strictly numbers, alphabets, underscore and spaces

If you need words from the matched lines, then spilt using space as delimiter.

You can try python regex online on http://pythex.org/

Sample Run on IDLE

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$', 'ahz2gb_ f heyght78_')[0].split(' ')
['ahz2gb_', 'f', 'heyght78_']
```

---

`EDIT`: Given new requirement of only having words, here is how you can achieve the same.

```
import re
mylist =  'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_'.split(' ')
r = re.compile("^[0-9a-zA-Z_]+$")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, mylist))
print(newlist)
```

Wish, I could shorten it!!

Sample Run

```
========= RESTART: C:/regex.py =========
['ahz2gb_', 'heyght78_']
```

Comment: actually, I'm looking to pick out the whole word, that is literals between spaces.  The above puts all single literals into a list.

Comment: you can add space also as one of the valid character in list and then once you have the line match which has your desired characters you can split on line with space.

Comment: I'm sorry using `b = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_')` produces an empty list.  I'm trying to build a list

Comment: Sorry `b = split(re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_'))` produces and error and so does `b = split(re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_'), " ")`

Comment: Thanks, but this includes 'f' into the list and I'm trying to exclude the word $f since it contains a character which is not a letter, a number or an underscore.

Comment: I couldn't find single line solution but wrote code for your requirement. It should solve your problem. Check later part of my solution after `EDIT`

Answer (score 4):

There is `\w` for capturing those characters, and you need to allow more than one character with `+`:

```
b = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_')
```

As `+` is greedy, you don't really need the `\b` either:

```
b = re.findall(r'\w+', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_')
```

If you need words to be split by white space only (not `\b`), then you can use look-around:

```
b = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_')
```

The `(?<!` sequence means: look back to see you don't have the pattern that follows `(?<!` preceding the current matching position in the target string. So in this case `(?<!\S)` means: there should not be a preceding non-white-space character.

Then `(?!` is similar, but looking forward (without matching).

Comment: @Sayse, Isn't that what the break is intended to do? Depends on what is the definition of a "word"

Comment: I agree the definition could be expanded upon, the op's edit appears to suggest this "word" should be omitted

Comment: Ok, I added a third alternative to my answer.

Comment: I amended it to b = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_]+', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_') (sorry I don't know how to dileneate code in comments) but that outputs [ahz2gb_, f, heyght78_].  It's supposed to be the case that the second word is not put in the list because it contains $.

Comment: (Use backticks to wrap code in comments.). See third alternative in my answer which does not include `f` in the output.

Comment: what's a backtick?

Comment: That is this character: `. A quote that goes in the opposite direction.

Comment: Also I do not understand b = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_').  I haven't seen yet what the characters ! < and S are meant to do.  Where is that written down?

Comment: Added a short explanation of `(?<!` and `(?!`. For more info look for "look around" in the context of regular expressions. For example [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: @Trincot, thanks, got it. I really appreciate you doing that.

Comment: @Trincot `b = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_')`, this works, but for the record is there another way to accomplish the task along the lines of `b = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', 'ahz2gb_ $f heyght78_')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150703/discussion-between-bobsmith76-and-trincot).